# How to execute commands after grid engine's qsub job's done in shell script?

Tags: shell, qsub

I am right now writing a shell script including some qsub jobs parallel in working nodes and then a summary statistics will be summarized and write into a file "temperature.txt". However, the local command will be execute right after qsub summit the job to the nodes. Is there anything like "wait [pid]" can be applied to qsub job id?

My code looks like below:

```
echo "Burning..."
var=0
while [ $var -ne 1 ]
do
    qsub -hold_jid update -t 1-$1:1 -N mcmc_bn_$T -S /bin/sh -j y -cwd ./bn_mcmc.sh # Submit mcmc
    qsub -hold_jid mcmc_bn_$T  -N update update.sh $1
    T=$(tail -n 1 ./temp/temperature.txt)
    echo $T
    var=$(awk 'BEGIN{ print "'$T'"<1}') # when $T<1 => $var=1
    echo $var
done
```

Thanks in advance!

Rui

Comment: I'm reasonably familiar with R and I don't see the reason for that tag.

Comment: @42-sorry for this tag. My .sh script contains some R script, I added it without thinking...

Comment: Use the `-e` epilogue option to specify a script that will be ran after job completion.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Thanks! Do you mean put the local command into another script, say test.sh, and call it by sh -e test.sh? Could you please explain more?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong to mention `-e`. To specify custom epilogue script you could do `qsub -l epilogue=test.sh [...other qsub options] command`. This is supposed to run test.sh after completion of `command`.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Thanks for your suggestion. I was not clear. I actually want to run the command `T=$(tail -n 1 ./temp/temperature.txt)`
after the previous qsub processes done on working nodes not reversely.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone envolved in this discussion.

I found a solution through a script from: http://ccn.ucla.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_have_a_script_wait_for_jobs_before_proceeding

Basic he/she wrote a script call `jobhold.sh` to check `qstat` every 30s (could be specified). The code is simple as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# jobhold.sh
# JB 8/2010
# usage: 
#       jobhold.sh qsub <my_command>
#       jobhold.sh q.sh <my_command>
# For commands that are submitted to cluster, hold until jobs have completed
shopt -s expand_aliases
sleep_time=30 # seconds; don't make this too short! don't want to tax system with excessive qstat calls
me=`whoami`
alias myqstat='qstat | grep $me'
stdout=`$@` # call the command and capture the stdout
id=`echo $stdout | awk -F' ' '{print $3}'` # get the jobid
status=`myqstat | grep $id` # check to see if job is running
while [ -n "$status" ] # while $status is not empty
do
    sleep $sleep_time
status=`myqstat | grep $id`
done
```

By putting this script before the commands next, they will be run after all `qsub` jobs done. Please keep posting if you got other thoughts or more efficient way to solve this. Thanks!

Best,

Rui